# automapper profile class uses existing mapping definition

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have 3 classes: A, B and C where both A and B should be converted to C while A is a wrapper of B:

```
public class C
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    // other properties ...
}

public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    // other properties ...
}

public class A
{
    public int IdA { get; set; }
    public B Data { get; set; }
}
```

And I use the auto mapper profile class to create the mappings:

```
public class MapperProfile: Profile
{
    public MapperProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<B, C>();
        CreateMap<A, C>();
    }
}
```

When mapping from A to C, I would like to overwrite C's `Id` with A's `IdA` while everything else in `Data` to populate the other properties in C which is effectively the mapping defined with `CreateMap<B, C>()`.

A search on stackoverflow suggests to use `ConvertUsing` but that needs a mapper instance while I don't have an instance in the `Profile` class. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ConverUsing` overload to achieve this. Here what your mapping profile would look like:

```
 CreateMap<B, C>();
 CreateMap<A, C>()
        .ConvertUsing((src, dst, ctx) =>
        {
            var c = ctx.Mapper.Map<C>(src.Data);
            c.Id = src.IdA;
            return c;
        });
```